# SharePoint Designer 2010 : Sending email to multiple users

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer

I have 2 lists Requests & Domain Leaders  and once the request item changed automatic notification send to all domain leaders based on his domain

### Request :

### Title   :  Domain

R1      :  EMEA

R2      :  ASIA

### Domain Owner :

### Title : Owner

EMEA  : Ahmed Ali

EMEA  : Sayed Anwar

ASIA  : Jing Ja

ASIA  : Jacki Sho

So if request R1 has been updated I need to send 2 separate mails to EMEA domain owners : Ahmed Ali & Syed Anwar . How can I implement it using SharePoint designer 2010 workflow ?

Comment: Make the Owner field a person/group column that allows for multiple values. Then you simply use this field when you want to email the users based on the domain

Comment: Thanks Eric , Can you please add this comment in answers below so I can make it answer for my question . I have another question in notification it self can I say show only first name for the owners e.g. Dear Ahmed , Sayed , Is it possible as I see right now that the available options are to show display names , emails or IDs I don not find first name in available list .

Comment: They don't expose that to you unfortunately. If you wanted to do that, you might need to create a contacts list with that information and pull it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically make the Owner field a person/group column that allows for multiple values. Then you simply use this field when you want to email the users based on the domain.

Answer (score 1):

First we need to create two groups in settings > site settings > site permissions > create group
1. EMEA Group
2. ASIA Group

In SharePoint Designer create List Workflow.

Work flow:

Update item in **this list**

Then Email **these Users**(EMEA Group)

Then Email **these Users**(EMEA Group)

When we save we need to check the check box **start workflow automatically when an item is created.**

Comment: Thanks Ravi , I already proposed this solution to my client but he told me its not accepted as each time he need to add new contact he will request from admin guy to do that so he need to make it more flexible . I know that this solution is easier than when my client needs but it client . Is it doable to loop over list and send to these mails ?